# extjs data not display

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I tried to do this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function() {
Ext.create('BVCore.Grid', {
    id:'gridServiceCatalogAll',
    renderTo: 'gridServiceCatalogAll',
    stateId: 'gridServiceCatalogAll',       
    store: Ext.create('BVCore.LocalStore', {
        fields: ['id', {name:'category', type:'string', mapping:'category.name'}, 'name', 'equipment', 'sizeMin', 'sizeMax', 'description', 'annualCharge'],
        groupField : 'category',
        proxy: {
            url:  '<spring:url value="/controller/search/json/serviceCatAll.json" />'               
        },
    }),
    features: [{ftype:'grouping'}],
    columns: [
              {text: '<spring:message code="serviceModel.category" />', dataIndex: 'category'},
              {text: '<spring:message code="serviceModel.description" />', dataIndex: 'description'},
              {text: '<spring:message code="serviceModel.annualCharge" arguments="${year}" />', dataIndex: 'annualCharge'}                       
          ]
}); 
});
</script>
```

but the field category is not recognized and so is not displayed.

Do you know why it's not displayed ?

Comment: What does the response look like coming back from the server, can you share your json?

Comment: Is header displayed only data is missing, or there's also no header?